# Intent crashes my app

Tags: android

I am currently trying to call another activity via a `OptionsMenuItem` using `Intent`. I have 2 layouts. The 1st layout has a `EditText` with a string that is retrieved from a database. The 2nd layout also have a `EditText` which is empty. The `OptionsMenuItem` is in the 1st layout. Whenever I click on the `MenuItem`, it is supposed to call up the 2nd layout and extract the text from the 1st layout into the `EditText` in the 2nd layout, but instead it crashes. I tried using the ActivityResult way but I still can't get it to work. Hope you guys can help me out.

This is my java code where the intent is for the main activity with the 1st layout:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    // Build the menus that are shown when editing.
    if (mState == STATE_EDIT) {
        menu.add(0, REVERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_revert)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_revert);
        if (!mNoteOnly) {
            menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
            menu.add(1, ADD_ID, 1, R.string.add_namespace);
            menu.add(2, MENU_ITEM_ADD, 2, R.string.menu_add);
        }

    // Build the menus that are shown when inserting.
    } else {
        menu.add(0, DISCARD_ID, 0, R.string.menu_discard)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
            menu.add(1, ADD_ID, 1, R.string.add_namespace);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle all of the possible menu actions.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case DELETE_ID:
        deleteNote();
        finish();
        break;
    case DISCARD_ID:
        cancelNote();
        break;
    case REVERT_ID:
        cancelNote();
        break;
    case ADD_ID:
     addNamespace();
     break;
    case MENU_ITEM_ADD:
     testActivity();
         break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private final void testActivity()
{
 Intent i = new Intent(this, TitleEditor.class);
 startActivityForResult(i, STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 switch(requestCode)
 {
  case(STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE):
  {
   if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
   {
    newTextTemplate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsTemplate);
String newTemplate = data.getStringExtra(TitleEditor.PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER);
    newTextTemplate.setText(newTemplate);
   }
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

This is my java code with the 2nd layout:

```
public class TitleEditor extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
            NotePad.Notes._ID, // 0
            NotePad.Notes.TITLE, // 1
            NotePad.Notes.TEMPLATE, // 2
    };

    private static final int COLUMN_INDEX_TITLE = 1;
    private static final int COLUMN_INDEX_TEMPLATE = 2;

    private Cursor mCursor;

    private EditText mToContacts;
    private EditText mFromTemplate;

 public static final String PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER = null;

    private Uri mUri;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.title_editor);

        mUri = getIntent().getData();

        mCursor = managedQuery(mUri, PROJECTION, null, null, null);

        mFromTemplate = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.smsTemplate);
        mFromTemplate.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
  resultIntent.putExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER, NoteEditor.smsTemplate);
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

My logcat requested by srinathhs:
11-22 04:39:12.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.notepad/com.example.android.notepad.TitleEditor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:574)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:147)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1493)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at com.example.android.notepad.TitleEditor.onCreate(TitleEditor.java:84)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
11-22 04:39:12.815: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(456):     ... 11 more

Comment: There must be a stack trace when your application crashed. Can you add that here ?

Comment: What's the crash? See my most viewed question (click my name) for a common oversight.

Comment: @srinathhs: if you are talking about LogCat i can post it up. But I dun see any errors in it though.

Comment: I have no idea how to format my logcat such that it will appear nicely. I tried to add in my manifest code for that second activity but unable to do so since it only shows me 1 line of sentence.

Comment: Okay i found the stack trace. If I'm not wrong the error should be the nullpointerexception. Correct me if I'm wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is closed. I accidentally found the answer to solve this error. It seems that 2 lines of my code is interfering with creating the 2nd activity. Thanks people ^^

Answer (score 3):

Quick question, did you register the 2nd activity within your manifest?  If not, that'll crash the application every time it would be invoked.

Comment: Yes, the activity is registered in the manifest file. No idea what is wrong with my code.